# Define imports in Play routes files per file

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have multiple routes files in a module. I also use custom *PathBindable*.

Implicits for *PathBindable* are added using

```
routesImport += "routessupport.PathBinders._"
```

in *build.sbt*.

The problem is that they are not needed in every route file, only in some of them.

However, with *routesImport* imports are added to every route file. As a result the imports are unused in some routes files and the compilation fails (custom scalac settings).

Can I somehow add imports per route file? 
I was digging but couldn't find a way. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Doubt there is any solution. Use `silencer` as workaround to ignore those warnings specifically.

Comment: This solution I know :)